# Should I favor the results of a Hotelling's $T^2$ or Bonferroni confidence interval?

Tags: confidence-interval, inference, multivariate-analysis, bonferroni, hotelling-t2

I am trying to understand if my reasoning is correct about these two methods. Faced with a situation where it is impossible to get both methods to fail to reject the null hypothesis, which should I trust or choose?

For example, you have a vector of means from a sample. After production of another large sample, you want to check that the new sample vector of means matches the old one. For this first test you fail to reject the null hypothesis based on the $T^2$ confidence region, but reject it based on the Bonferroni one.

You proceed to produce a second large sample and do the same test. Only this time you get inversed results. Based on the $T^2$ confidence region we reject the null hypothesis and based on the Bonferroni method we do not reject it.

Let's assume that producing a vector of means that satisfies both tests is impossible. Under this assumption which test should I trust?

If the items produced in our hypothetical case are prone to fraud, is it correct to assume that narrower simultaneous confidence intervals are preferred (in which case we would favor the Bonferroni method)?

Comment: 1) You never accept the null hypothese. Never use this wording, as it does not have sense. Null hypothesis can be only rejected with a test. 2) Use Hotelling test, as Bonfrerroni correction is known to be way too much conservative.

Comment: Would it be okay to word is a "fail to reject"?

Comment: It is. Fail to reject is the most common formulation I guess.

Comment: I'll edit the question to fix this, but thanks a lot for the info, and for the input on the Bonferroni thing.